# What is a grep pattern for matching lines?

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to find all cases in my test suite where one-line `it` methods are used back to back. Basically, I'm looking for files that have lines like these:

```rb
it { expect(some_stuff).to be_true }
it { expect(other_stuff).to be_false }
```

but not this:

```rb
it { expect(some_stuff).to be_true }
# a bunch of other stuff
it { expect(other_stuff).to be_true }
```

and can't quite figure out the pattern. I have tried:

```sh
> grep it.\{*\}\n*it ./test/directory -lR
# and
> grep it.\{*\}\n*it.\{*
```

which returns nothing, but I know there is at least one matching file. Does anyone know how to create the pattern I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you might be looking for is `/(?:it.*$)\n(?:it.*$)/`

But the problem you might be facing with `grep` or `egrep` is that this utility searches through a file single line at a time, so it doesn't support let say `\n` in a regular expression.

So you might want to look for other options than just `grep`.

[grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) manual page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[pcgregrep](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html):

```
pcregrep -lr -M "it.{.*}\nit" ./test/directory
```